# SQL Server 2008 Express - Install

Tags: sql, sql-server

It may sounds stupid, but I install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (express edition).

I want to make a new query, but I don't find the window that make it. As I understood, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 gives me the option to use and write a schema.

Where can I find this option? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you only installed the database engine.  You need to install Sql Server Management Studio to do that.

If you're using a licensed version then it should be a feature you can select when you install the instance.

If you're using Express then you can find it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8961

When you install the express version though, be aware that the installation procedure should be followed as though you are creating a new instance of sql server.  It's very unintuitive and most people naturally think they should be modifying an existing instance when installing management studio express... I personally wasted an hour trying to figure this out long ago.

Comment: Thanks, Can you tell me how I know my server name in Sql Server Management Studio?

Comment: If you didn't specifically provide one then it will either be "SqlExpress" if you are using the express version, or it will be an unnamed instance if you are using a licensed version.  And you always prefix it with your computer name so it would either be ComputerName\SqlExpress or just ComputerName.  Alternatively, you can just use a "." if you are specifying your local computer.  So ".\SqlExpress" or just ".".

Comment: If you gave the instance a name then you will have to use that name.  When you click 'Connect', and then 'Database Engine...', you can click the Server Name dropdown and then '<Browse for more...>' to list any instances it can find.  However, I believe that will only work if the Sql Browser service is running which may not be enabled by default (if it's not then you can enable it in manually in the system services).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is **SQL Server Management Studio**. You can use it to create databasese, tables, stored proces, run queries etc. You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593)